# Dynamic form validation in reactjs using json data

Tags: json, validation, reactjs, dynamic

I have below json with all the field properties in it

```
const BILL_NUMBER = [
{
    "caseIndex": "Bill Number",
    "minLength":"3",
    "maxLength": "16",
    "htmlControlType": "text",
    "errorMessage": "Alphanumeric Only",
    "idxReglrExp":"^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\s]*$",
    "cssClassName":"form-control"
}
];
```

below is the function to render the json data and the field is getting displayed in the page

```
renderBillNumber: function () {

    const data = BILL_NUMBER;
    return data.map(group => {
        return <div>
                <label for="billnumber">{group.caseIndex}</label>
                                    <input type={group.htmlControlType} className={group.cssClassName} id="billnumber" placeholder=""/>
                                    </div>
    });

},
```

I want to validate this field with the properties from the json like minlength,maxlength and to display error message based on the regex.

Can anyone help me how to do this in reactjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `onChange` property that will do the check for you:

```
renderBillNumber: function () {
  const data = BILL_NUMBER;
  return data.map(group => 
    <div>
      <label for="billnumber">{group.caseIndex}</label>
      <input 
        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, group)}
        type={group.htmlControlType}
        className={group.cssClassName} 
      />
    </div>
  });
},
handleChange(event, group) {
  const value = event.target.value;
  if (value.length < group.minLength) {
    // do what you want to do if value is too small
  }
  // all you want to check
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you're going to have to keep track of the state of each of your inputs. If the idea here is that you'll have X amount of bill numbers in your JSON, then it might make sense to only keep track of ones that have errors in your state.

You might first create a validate function like so:

```
validateText(evt){
// Get the current user input for this input box
const userInput = evt.target.value;

// Grab the current errors state
const errors = this.state.errors || {};

// Cycle through your JSON to get the data you need
BILL_NUMBER.forEach(bill => {

    // If this is the right bill, then get the validation data we need.
    if (bill.caseIndex === evt.target.name){
        const minLength = bill.minLength;
        const maxLength = bill.maxLength;
        const re = bill.idxReglrExp;
        if (userInput.length >= minLength &&
            userInput.length <= maxLength &&
            userInput.match(re)){
                //We're valid - cycle through state & remove error if it's there.
        } else {
            // Add this caseIndex to your state:
            this.setState({
                errors: {
                    ...errors,
                    bill.caseIndex: true
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

},

Then you can edit your renderBillNumber function so that your function is called whenever the user inputs text. Also, you can either add a "name" attribute referring to your input, or similarly [assign a ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to it.

```
renderBillNumber: function () {

const data = BILL_NUMBER;
return data.map(group => {
    if (this.state.errors[caseIndex]){
        return (
            <div>error</div>
        );
    } 
    return (
        <div>
            <label for="billnumber">{group.caseIndex}</label>
            <input name={group.caseIndex} onInput={this.validateText} type={group.htmlControlType} className={group.cssClassName} id="billnumber" placeholder=""/>
        </div>
    )
});
```

}

With this, validateText will be called when user inputs anything. If the state is changed, your bills will be rerendered with the appropriate visuals.